# If the matrix $A^3 = 0$, is $A$ singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that if the cube power of a matrix is the null matrix, then the matrix itself is singular?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I first tried to find a matrix A that was not null but it's cube was. The only time I found a matrix matching this resulted in a singular matrix.

Comment: Hint. Think about determinants.

Comment: I think that I do get that the determinant of the matrix will be equal to zero, but is there a relation to the determinant and the power of a matrix?

Comment: the moment you can find some $A^2 x \neq 0$, $A$ has an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$

Comment: @Mndx  Yes.  For any two square matrices  $A, B$ of the same size, $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, so $\det(A^3)=(\det(A))^3$. What does $(\det A)^3=0$ tell you?

Comment: if (det A)^3 = 0, then det(A) = 0. I think that solves my problem.

Comment: @Mndx indeed, it does!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with $n \ge 1$, and choose any nonzero vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Then there are three possibilities:

- $Ax = 0$.  Then $x$ is a nonzero vector in the null space of $A$.
- $Ax \ne 0$, but $A^2 x = 0$.  Then $A x$ is a nonzero vector in the null space of $A$.
- $A^2 x \ne 0$, but $A^3 x = 0 \cdot x = 0$.  Then $A^2 x$ is a nonzero vector in the null space of $A$.

Comment: Could you enlighten me on the notation of Ax here? What does the x stand for?

Comment: $x$ is the nonzero (column) vector that you chose, and $Ax$ is the product of the matrix with the $n\times 1$ column vector.

Answer (score 2):

A determinant free solution could be more enlightening. Note that if $A^3=0$ that then $im A^2 \subset ker A$ now there are two options. Either $im A^2=0$ and A is non-singular or not and then $A$ is singular (as $dim Ker A>0$) Do you see why the first case can not be true?