# True or false: If $A^3 = 0$ , $A$ is not invertible. Justify answer.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

can you help me with my homework:

If $A^3 = 0$ , is $A$ not invertible? and please justify why.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: What hapens if $A$ was.

Comment: Do you know any invariants that tell us whether a matrix is invertible or not?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend not to respond well, or at all, to questions like these that look like routine homework exercises and which show no effort.  What have you tried?   People will gladly meet you half way if you give us some sense of your attempts and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is invertible and $x \neq 0$. Can $A^3 x = 0$?

Comment: Hint: If $A$ was invertible, there would exist a matrix $B$, such that ... Then, calculate $A^3\cdot B^3$ in two different ways and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3138158/496634

Comment: This question has been asked several times this week by your classmates.  Ask them.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

$$\det(MN) = \det(M)\det(N)$$

Comment: That was a massive hint. Please give the OP time to respond to the comments

Comment: @bounceback Thanks for the advice, but I think I'm experienced enough to know how this site works: **"Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in the comments."**

Comment: I'm not talking about the site rules. I'm talking about maths pedagogy.

Comment: @bounceback You might be in the wrong place then.

Comment: A site for helping people with mathematics? You aren't making sense.

Comment: @FlybyNight thank you for the hint!

Comment: @bounceback You're on a site with specific rules, and a specific culture; a consensus-built order. We're all here to help people with Maths... but within the parameters set by the site, its rules and its community. If you think the rules conflict with pedagogy, and that people should behave differently to the established, consensus-built order then: you might be in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

If a matrix $A$ satisfying

$A^3 = 0 \tag 1$

*were* invertible, there would exist a matrix $B$ such that

$AB = BA = I; \tag 2$

then

$A^2 = IA^2 = (BA)A^2 = B(A^3) = B(0) = 0; \tag 3$

going a step further in the same direction yields

$A = IA = (BA)A = B(A^2) = B(0) = 0; \tag 4$

but clearly the $0$ matrix is not invertible; thus the assumptions (1) and (2) are, taken together, inherently contradictory.  Therefore no matrix satisfying (1) may also satisfy (2).

***Nota Bene:*** In fact it is easily seen that this result generalizes to the case

$A^k = 0, \; \text{some} \; k \in \Bbb N; \tag 5$

that is, no invertible matrix satisfies (5). ***End of Note.***

Answer (score 1):

A couple of methods of attack have already been proposed, Jan Villapaz, have they helped you?

Hamam Abdallah said "What happens if A was" (I presume be means "what happens if A was nverstible").  Suppose A has an inverse, A^{-1}.  What happens if you multiply both sides of A^3= 0 repeatedly by A^{-1}?

"Fly by Night" and several other pointed out that det(AB)= det(A)det(B).  If det(A^3)= det(0)= 0, what can you say about det(A)?  And what about the invertibility of A?